# JRE or JDK must be available for installing STS 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to install Spring Tool Suite. I have successfully installed it. But when I am opening the application, it gives me this warning

[image: Warning]

I have jdk and jre both installed in my laptop

```
 (C:\Program Files\Java)
```

I have also added the jdk path in my environment variable by setting variable name

```
 JAVA_HOME
```

and path is

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1.
```

My java version

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
```

I have also verified my path using echo %JAVA_HOME% and the path is correct. 
Can anybody help me why I am I still getting this error? Is there any step that I am missing?

Comment: you have java 12 installed, yet it is java 8?

Comment: Do I need to install java 8 ?

Comment: I'd recommend installing choco (https://chocolatey.org/install) and using that to install Java for you, it will set up the path and env variables etc, so you will not face any manual errors

Comment: @Unknown no, you claim you already did, yet you also claim it's java 12 you have installed

Comment: This is my java version "1.8.0_211"

Comment: "and path is

 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1." how is that 1.8.0_211?

Comment: You get your java path by running echo %JAVA_HOME% in your cmd. And I got "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1" .

Comment: @Unknown your java path tells you you have Java 12 installed but when running java version it tells you Java 8 is installed. Seems like you have an inconsistency

Comment: please make sure that both have same  bit 32 or 64 and check in system path variable which version you have configured

Answer (score 0):

I think in your system have both java 12 and 8 verison, try to configure java 8 version in system path variable and check once, and please make sure that both( jdk and sts) have same bit 32 or 64.